# Are Longs in java too harsh ? Why so?

Tags: java, wrapper, long-integer

I have a Long variable say,

```
private Long m_prevPacketRecvdTime = null;
```

now I have a setter/getter pair for it,

```
    public void setM_prevPacketRecvdTime() {
        if (this.m_prevPacketRecvdTime == null) {
            this.m_prevPacketRecvdTime = new Long(System.currentTimeMillis());
        } else {
            // Why to create a new Object every time
                    //Why I can't just set the new value
                    //Why use new operator here instead of an Assignment or set method call
        }
    }
```

Instead of traditional setter method I thought to improve it, by 1. passing long instead of Long, 2. Creating a new Long only once and rest of the time just setting the new value to existing Long object. But to my disbelief there is no such method in [Long](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html).

Do we really need to create a  new Long object every time we want to change its value, How can we set a new long value to existing Long object (just opposite of longvalue()) ?

**More Info**
While Searching for the answer I also came across [AtomicLong](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html), which has similar functionalities, But I am not sure whether that can be useful for me or not. Because they clearly say AtomicLong "**cannot be used as a replacement for a Long.**"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot, and it's deliberate.  Immutable objects have *many* advantages -- thread safety, ease of use, security and predictability among other things.  See Effective Java item 15 for additional reasons, but the wrapper classes in Java are all immutable.

That said, you should use `Long.valueOf(long)` (or autoboxing) instead of `new Long`, because `Long.valueOf` knows to cache commonly used values.

Allocation is relatively cheap in Java.  Don't worry too much about it.  If you can produce *hard numbers* to prove that switching to your own custom mutable wrapper type is worth the additional code complexity, then do that, but the traditional immutable wrappers are perfectly serviceable.

Comment: +1, for such a nice answer, I really expected this answer.. However I am still not convinced with the fact that every time I need to create a new Object, isn't there any better way ? Long.valueOf(long) is good but ultimately that will also return a new object... Any ways thanks

Comment: Creating a new Long is very, very, VERY fast. Don't pre-optimize.

Comment: Stop thinking of objects as expensive.  They really aren't.  But the only alternative is to create your own `MutableLong` class that wraps a `long`.

Answer (score 2):

If performance is the most important aspect, you should consider:

```
private long m_prevPacketRecvdTime = 0;

public void setM_prevPacketRecvdTime() {
    if (this.m_prevPacketRecvdTime == 0) {
        this.m_prevPacketRecvdTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
}
```

It's not just faster but also simpler. Please note the 'special value' 0 which means 'not set'. For time fields I believe it's OK.

Another item to consider is the use of `System.currentTimeMillis()`. It is a relatively slow operation, possibly even slower than allocating a new object (using `new Long()`). Improving this is a bit more tricky. One option might be to keep the current time up to date in a different thread:

```
while (!stopped) {
    Thread.sleep(100);
    currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

and then instead of calling `System.currentTimeMillis()` every time just access the (static) field `currentTime` instead.

Comment: +1 You can also use `Long.MIN_VALUE` as not set. I also use `Long.MAX_VALUE` for timeouts which are "not set".

Comment: @anDroider why exactly do you need `java.lang.Long`? You can always convert a `long` to a `java.lang.Long` where needed.

Comment: this variable is used by multiple thread... so every time before accessing it I lock this variable using synchronized(){}, Same functionality is not available for long, only other option is to make synchronized getter/setters...I will now try the second approach (synchronized getters / setters for long) hence eliminating the need of Long...

Comment: It doesn't make sense to synchronize on java.lang.Long. Synchronized getter and setters might make sense, but `AtomicLong` would be faster because this would eliminate the need to synchronize (see the docs for `AtomicLong`).